# How can I disable dbstop if error in MATLAB

Tags: debugging, matlab

If often happens that I type `dbstop if error` in the MATLAB command line to catch and debug errors, but other than going to the debug menu and to the window (which I don't know how to find it in the new 2012b version) is there a way to disable `dbstop if error` in command line?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the documentation of [`dbclear`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/dbclear.html)

> `dbclear if error` Removes the breakpoints set using the `dbstop if error` and `dbstop if error identifier` statements.